# class 'Pipe' has no attribute set_height()

Tags: python

```
class Pipe:
    GAP = 200
    VEL = 5

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x 
        self.height = 0
        self.gap = 100

        self.top = 0
        self.bottom = 0
        self.PIPE_TOP = pygame.transform.flip(PIPE_IMG, False, True)
        self.PIPE_BOTTOM = PIPE_IMG

        self.passed = False
        self.set_height()
    def set_height(self):
        self.height = random.randrange(50 ,450)
        self.top = self.height - self.PIPE_TOP.get_height()
        self.bottom = self.height + self.GAP

    def move(self):
        self.x -= self.VEL

    def draw(self, win):
        win.blit(self.PIPE_TOP, (self.x, self.top))
        win.blit(self.PIPE_BOTTOM, (self.x, self.bottom))

    def collide(self,bird):
        bird_mask = bird.get_mask()
        top_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.PIPE_TOP)
        bottom_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.PIPE_BOTTOM)

        top_offset = (self.x - bird.x, self.top - round(bird.y))
        bottom_mask = (self.x - bird.x, self.bottom - round(bird.y) )

        b_point = bird_mask.overlap(bottom_mask, bottom_offset)
        t_point = bird_mask.overlap(top_mask, top_offset)

        if t_point or b_point:
            return True
            
        return False
```

Although, I have used a text editor for the program, but I don't know why the indentations got wrong. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Indentation matters in Python - `set_height` is a nested function, **not** a method.

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe said, indentation matters. You nested `set_height`, which means it isn't a method of the class.

Just unindent it by four spaces, and you're done!

Code:

```py
class Pipe:
    GAP = 200
    VEL = 5

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x 
        self.height = 0
        self.gap = 100

        self.top = 0
        self.bottom = 0
        self.PIPE_TOP = pygame.transform.flip(PIPE_IMG, False, True)
        self.PIPE_BOTTOM = PIPE_IMG

        self.passed = False
        self.set_height()
    def set_height(self):
        self.height = random.randrange(50 ,450)
        self.top = self.height - self.PIPE_TOP.get_height()
        self.bottom = self.height + self.GAP
```

Hope this helps!